# Twitter integration in iOS app

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, twitter-fabric

In my `ios` app I'm trying to integrate twitter with fabric and i followed all the docs provided by fabric
 https://docs.fabric.io/ios
I have a problem when i build my app then some error

> 1.TwitterCore.framework/Headers/TwitterCore.h:20:9: 'Cocoa/Cocoa.h' file not found
>
> 2.TwitterKit.framework/Headers/TwitterKit.h:12:9: Could not build module 'TwitterCore'
>
> 3.AppDelegate.m:14:9: Could not build module 'TwitterKit'

so i am unable to build app.

Comment: Are you using Cocoapods for fabric integration ?

Comment: No i'm not using cocoapods, I just manually install fabric and run it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the exact same issue, the Cocoa/Cocoa.h header is for OS X, since we are doing iOS, I removed this header. Open your TwitterCore.h

This snippet

```
#if IS_UIKIT_AVAILABLE
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#else
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#endif
```

Becomes

```
#if IS_UIKIT_AVAILABLE
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#endif
```

And now my project builds just fine.