# Twitter Kit Integration issues in iOS app

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I want to integrate twitter in iOS Application, I tried using Fabric as well as by using Cocoa pod but getting same error every time.

Following are the Errors:

1. Could Not build TwitterCore
2. Cocoa/Cocoa.h file not found
3. Could Not build Module TwitterKit

I searched and tried some solutions as per given below links but nothing work for me. I am using xcode 6.4, ios 8.4.
Please give me any correct solution.

I went through below link
[Twitter integration in iOS app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34556349/twitter-integration-in-ios-app)
but didnt help

TwitterKit issue comming
https://twittercommunity.com/t/could-not-build-objective-c-module-twitterkit/49551

Cocoa/Cocoa.h file not found
[Cocoa/Cocoa.h file not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15826825/cocoa-cocoa-h-file-not-found)

Answer (score 0):

Go to project settings --> Build settings

- Click on All tab and search "allow non"

then set **YES** to **Allow Non-modular Includes in Framework** option

[image]

Comment: I did that also but no use.

Comment: @DevyaniShinde I would request please follow [**this**](https://docs.fabric.io/ios/twitter/twitterkit-setup.html) step by step, start from Introduction step. it worked for me.